# Python: How to distinguish between long, short button press and click

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to have a simple GUI with 4 buttons. If you just click the button, function A should be executed, for short button press (e.g.1sec) function B should be executed and finally a long press (e.g. > 2s) function C should be executed.
Imagine a counter.
If you click the button, it will be reset to 0
If you short press the button, counter will be increased by 1 for e.g t=1sec
If you long press the button, counter will be increased by 10 until button is released.

Is somebody haveing an idea. I was trying this to accomplish it with a 2nd thread but I haven't found a possibility to stop the thread like you can start it

Comment: record time at LEFT_DOWN and then difference it against LEFT_UP ... without knowing what GUI package you are using you will be unlikely to get better help than that. ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is easy to do in PyQt if you use a widget which inherits QAbstractButton. No need for any timers or separate threads. Just use the built-in [auto-repeat](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop) functionality, and keep a record of the current state.

Here's a simple demo:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QPushButton.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setAutoRepeat(True)
        self.setAutoRepeatDelay(1000)
        self.setAutoRepeatInterval(1000)
        self.clicked.connect(self.handleClicked)
        self._state = 0

    def handleClicked(self):
        if self.isDown():
            if self._state == 0:
                self._state = 1
                self.setAutoRepeatInterval(50)
                print 'press'
            else:
                print 'repeat'
        elif self._state == 1:
            self._state = 0
            self.setAutoRepeatInterval(1000)
            print 'release'
        else:
            print 'click'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = Button('Test Button')
    button.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

in wxPython I would do it like this ... however you may need to adjust it for your GUI library ...

```
start_time = None
def onLeftDown(e):
    global running 
    running = True
    ct =0 
    while running:
        ct += 1
        do_something(ct)

def onLeftUp(e):
    print "You Pressed For %s Seconds!"%(time.time()-start_time)

my_btn = wx.Button(parent,-1,"Click Me!")
my_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,onLeftDown)
my_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP,onLeftUp)
```

Im not very familliar with QT but maybe you can modify this wx code to do what you want...

```
import wx
ct = 0
def counting():
    global running
    global ct
    if running:
        ct +=1
        print ct
        wx.CallLater(1,counting)
    else:
        print "OK DONE COUNTING AT:",ct
def onLeftDown(evt):
    global running
    running = True
    counting()

def onLeftUp(evt):
    print "STOP NOW!!"
    global running 
    running = False

a = wx.App(redirect=False)
f = wx.Frame(None,-1,"asdasd")

b = wx.Button(f,-1,"Click Me")

b.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,onLeftDown)
b.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP,onLeftUp)

f.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: the idea is, that the value of the counter is changed accordingly while the button is pressed. In your idea, the time has to be calculated after the button was released. I am using the Qt framework

Comment: why whats the difference in terms of function?

Comment: Just imagine a light dimmer. The level is changed while you are pressing the button and not once you have released the button. If you click it, light shall go ON 100%, if you keep button pressed the light shall start dim first slow but than faster.

Comment: ok I guess that makes sense...  updated the answer to show one way someone might do this with wxPython ... doubt its the best way...